# Why is flatMap different for Observable and Iterable while map is the same

Tags: scala

I was looking on Coursera on this lecture https://class.coursera.org/reactive-002/lecture/143 about Observables.

The lecturer says that `map` behaves the same for `Observable` and `Iterable` but `flatMap` behaves differently because `Observable` elements do not come in order.

Isn't it the same case for `map`?
Why is there no distinction when using `map`?

Comment: Can you elaborate what he means by "same"? Their monadic type is the same, but their actual behaviour is obviously different (as they act on different things).

Comment: By `same` I meant that in both cases results come asynchronously and therefore can not be ordered.

Comment: flatmap is about **chaining** observables together. while map() is about changing the **result type** of an observable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained pretty well in the lecture.

Map for both `Iterable` and `Observable` works the same, simply modifies each element using same function.

`List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + 1)` yields `List(1, 2, 3)`

It would make no sense for map on `Observable` to change the order, just whenever source `Observable` produces a value, mapped one produces a value that is the original, but with specific funtion applied to it. Order is preserved.

However `flatMap` takes a function `A => Observable[A]` so for each element it would create another `Observable`.

What you would have for `List` could be

```
List(1, 10, 100).flatMap(n => List(n + 1, n + 2, n + 3))
```

whould yield

```
List(2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 101, 102, 103)
```

you can think of it as if that function would yield

```
List(List(2, 3, 4), List(11, 12, 13), List(101, 102, 103))
```

and then concat them them (flatten the list).

And if you were to do the same for `Observables`, for each element you would yield an `Observable` that creates it's values asynchronously, you don't know when they will appear. So essentially you would have 3 Observables:

```
Observable(2, 3, 4), Observable(11, 12, 13), Observable(101, 102, 103)
```

and when they are merged, you don't know what the order of elements will be, you can only be sure that 3 will come before 4 and 102 will be before 103, but not whether it will start with 11 or 2 or maybe 101.

This is why `flatMap` for `Iterables` works differently than for `Observables`. On `Iterables` order is determined, however for `Observables` you can't what the order of elements would be. This is exactly what the picture shows

[image]

One of blue marbels came before the last green marble. That wouldn't be the case with `Iterables`, you would have 2 red, 2 green and 2 blue in this order.